# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation Upload File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, reactjs

i get a problem when upload file image use front-end ReactJS and back-end PHP.

**onChange in form**

```
onImageChange: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        image: e.target.files[0]
    });
},
```

**Send data to back-end**

```
$.post('api/update.php', {  
    image: this.state.image
},
function(res) {
    this.setState({successUpdate: res});
}.bind(this));
e.preventDefault();
```

**Back-end (PHP)**

```
$product->image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

$product->id = $_POST['id'];
$result = $product->create() ? "true" : 'false';
```

The problem was : 
1. **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation** 
2. **how to get the image data (directory, name, size, etc) using php from reactjs**

Comment: `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: @Lithilion, still error,Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.